# Conditional Expected Value and distribution question

Tags: probability, statistics

> The distribution of loss due to fire damage to a warehouse is:
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{r|l}
> \text{Amount of Loss (X)} & \text{Probability}\\
> \hline
> 0 & 0.900 \\
> 500 & 0.060  \\
> 1,000 & 0.030\\
> 10,000 & 0.008 \\
> 50,000 & 0.001\\
> 100,000 & 0.001 \\
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> Given that a loss is greater than zero, calculate the expected amount of the loss.

My approach is to apply the definition of expected value:

$$E[X \mid X>0]=\sum\limits_{x_i}x_i \cdot p(x_i)=500 \cdot 0.060 + 1,000 \cdot 0.030 + \cdots + 100,000 \cdot 0.001=290$$

I am off by a factor of 10--The answer is 2,900.  I am following the definition of expected value, does anyone know why I am off by a factor of $1/10$?

Should I be doing this instead???

$E[X \mid X>0] = \sum\limits_{x_i} (x_i \mid x_i > 0) \cdot \cfrac{\Pr[x_i \cap x_i>0]}{\Pr(x_i > 0)}$
Thanks.

Comment: The **conditional** probabilities given $X\gt 0$ are (except for the first one) the probabilities, **divided** by the probability that $X\gt 0$, that is, by $0.1$.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if most warehouse fires do nothing, or if warehouses are on fire 10% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You completely missed the word "given".  That means you want a *conditional* probability *given* the event cited.  In other words, your second option is right.

For example the *conditional* probability that $X=500$ *given* that $X>0$ is
$$
\Pr(X=500\mid X>0) = \frac{\Pr(X=500\ \&\ X>0)}{\Pr(X>0)} = \frac{\Pr(X=500}{\Pr(X>0)} = \frac{0.060}{0.1} = 0.6.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to divide by $\sum p(x_i)$.

Comment: Why?  Is this the proper def I should be using: $E[X \mid X>0] = \sum\limits_{x_i} (x_i \mid x_i > 0) \cdot \cfrac{\Pr[x_i \cap x_i>0]}{\Pr(x_i > 0)}$